# How to create a typescript enum from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have a list of currencies supported

```
export const CURRENCIES = ['EUR', 'CHF', 'GBP', 'USD', 'DKK'];
```

This is defined in a npm library.

I have a TS project where I am using currency code for a currency related component. This is the current implementation.

```
export Interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>{
currency?: 'USD' | 'EUR' | 'GBP'; // current implementation
}

const CurrencyInput = ({ currency = 'EUR'}:InputProps) => {
....
}
```

However, with the current implementation, the currency prop is restricted only to 'USD', 'EUR', and 'GBP'. I want to make the currency prop dynamic, so it can accept any currency code from the CURRENCIES array. I prefer to keep the supported currencies in the npm library, so that if I have to update the supported currency in future, i only need to update in one place because this currency constant is being used in multiple places.

Comment: You can use the new `as const` feature, then derive a type from that array: https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/

Answer (score 3):

If you declare your `CURRENCIES` array with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), you can just do the following:

```
export const CURRENCIES = ['EUR', 'CHF', 'GBP', 'USD', 'DKK'] as const;

type Currency = typeof CURRENCIES[number];
// type Currency = "EUR" | "CHF" | "GBP" | "USD" | "DKK"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using TypeScript's string literal types in combination with the `CURRENCIES` array defined in your npm library. Here's how you can modify your `InputProps` and `CurrencyInput` to accept any currency code from the `CURRENCIES` array:
Try this and see if it works:

```js
export const CURRENCIES = ['EUR', 'CHF', 'GBP', 'USD', 'DKK'];

export interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  currency?: typeof CURRENCIES[number]; // Use the type from the CURRENCIES array
}

const CurrencyInput = ({ currency = 'EUR' }: InputProps) => {
  // Your component implementation here
};
```

By using `typeof CURRENCIES[number]` as the type for the currency property, you are specifying that it should accept any value that is present in the `CURRENCIES` array.

Hope it helps!